# What is the equivalent argument field for source, source service tag and destination field in NSG security rules azure using teraform deployment

Tags: azure, terraform, terraform-provider-azure, azure-nsg

In the Source and Destination columns, VirtualNetwork, AzureLoadBalancer, and Internet are service tags, rather than IP addresses. How do i create this using terraform?

I am trying to create NSG on azure using terraform. While creating nsg security rules fields like source, source service tags and destination field is mandatory for creating nsg. How do i create this field using terraform ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could see `source_address_prefix` or `destination_address_prefix` in the [Argument Reference](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/azurerm/r/network_security_group.html#argument-reference). Tags such as ‘VirtualNetwork’, ‘AzureLoadBalancer’ and ‘Internet’ can also be used.

[image]

For example, you just need to add the specific service tag in the `source_address_prefix` and `destination_address_prefix` field.

```
 # VirtualNetwork
   security_rule {
     name                       = "RDP"
     priority                   = 300
     direction                  = "Inbound"
     access                     = "Allow"
     protocol                   = "Tcp"
     source_port_range          = "*"
     destination_port_range     = "80"
     source_address_prefix      = "VirtualNetwork"
     destination_address_prefix = "VirtualNetwork"
   }
#AppService
     security_rule {
     name                       = "SQL"
     priority                   = 310
     direction                  = "Inbound"
     access                     = "Allow"
     protocol                   = "Tcp"
     source_port_range          = "*"
     destination_port_range     = "80"
     source_address_prefix      = "AppService"
     destination_address_prefix = "*"
   }
```

**result**
[image]

Comment: source_address_prefix = "Service Tag" then what is the reference for source service tags field ?

Comment: I have attached a screenshot , i want to create similar fields using terraform

Comment: just need to add the specific service tag in the source_address_prefix and destination_address_prefix field.

Comment: So we have to only use source_address_prfix and destination_address_prefix parameters? does that means we can ignore the first field source as shown in screenshot? will terraform autopopulate the source field as service tag?

Comment: Yes, just ignore it. You can see expected result on my screenshot?

Comment: Then you should accept it as an answer refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).